# How to get DotNetBrowser to scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, vertical-scrolling, dotnetbrowser

I am having an issue where I need to be able to enable scrolling when there is overflow on a page.  I have it set in the CSS with `html {overflow-y: scroll;}` which brings up the scrollbar but it is grayed out and doesn't work.  Currently, the only way I can get to places that are lower is to tab through the form, but this is not really a solution so to speak, but a workaround.

Is there some special setting that allows scrolling to occur?  It's happening on html pages in the chromium browser and I need a solution for it.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the page for which such behavior is reproducible? Also, is the page handled in the same way in Google Chrome?

Comment: I ended up getting it fixed...one of the other CSS files I was using was overwriting the overflow and changing it to hidden.